# syntax error in alter table add column

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

got a syntax error saying near "," while compile in the following code:

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD " + TOADD1 + " VARCHAR," + TOADD2 + " VARCHAR," 
                + TOADD3 + " VARCHAR");
```

Where is the syntax error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't `varchar` need a length for SQLite? e.g. `varchar(20)`?

Comment: Also, what are the values provided for the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` supports only adding one column at a time as seen in the [syntax diagram](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

[image]

If you need to add three columns, split it to three separate `ALTER TABLE`s.